# problem with ftp pushing files and me not having access as regular user

Tags: linux, unix, permissions

I've run visudo and added my username to the list to be able to do whatever I need to rather than logging in as root user.

I have my svn push out file's through ftp as user www-data, and therefore when I try to cd into those directories, I get permission denied.

Any thoughts? Can I add my username to some config file somewhere to have access to all files?

Answer (score 0):

When you use sudo, you *are* running as the root user, but only for that particular command.  I think the easiest thing to do would be to ensure that you and www-data are in the same group, and set the group permissions accordingly. (e.g., chmod 775 yourdir)

Comment: hmmm, well I'm in the `users` group since I'm a regular user, and I don't want to add the www-data user to the `users` group. Couldn't that screw up some stuff? Or else I need it chmod'd 705 so that other users could at least see and view the directory contents..

Any thoughts?

Comment: A user can be a member of multiple groups--that's not a problem, so just add yourself to the www-data group as well.